# BuddyPress/BuddyVerified/JS/PHP - Make verified icon appear

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, buddypress

I am using [BuddyVerified](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-verified/) on my BuddyPress-enabled WordPress site.

The verification icons do not appear in the header of verified user profiles as they are intended to, however (probably due to some inconsistency with the theme). I attempt to append the verification icons to user profile headers by entering the below code into the site's custom Javascript box:

```
// Prepend to objects of class "user-nicename"...
$(".user-nicename").before(

  // this PHP code
  <?php 
        $ver_slug = basename(get_permalink());
        $ver_user = get_user_by('slug', $slug);
        $ver_user_id = $user->ID;
        $ver_user_is_verified = bp_is_verified($user_id);
        $ver_user_verified_icon = bp_verified_image($user_id);
    ?>

);

// Pass PHP boolean variable indicating user verification over to JS
var user_is_verified = <?php echo json_encode($ver_user_is_verified); ?>;

// If user is verified...
if (user_is_verified) {

    // Prepend user verification icon to "user-nicename"
    $(".user-nicename").before(
        <?php echo $ver_user_verified_icon ?>
    )

}
```

Here are the [BuddyVerified functions](http://hookr.io/plugins/buddyverified/2.4.1/functions/#index=b).

Seems logical. No result though. PHP is not my strong suit.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Is this being executed in the on ready of the document? Are there any errors in the console? Can you show us the resulting javascript that is generated from the php?

Comment: It is being executed on ready. There is no console. Idk what you mean by resulting Javascript. That code contains all of the Javascript.

Comment: The code you have written here is PHP that generates JavaScript. Looking at the actual javascript that results from this is often enlightening. By console I meant press F12 in your browser and see if there are any errors when it executes.